# Broken USB-drive not given a name with lsblk

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I dd'ed my 64gb flashdrive last week, and did not realise that the iso was corrupted until the dd was done.

The drive is no longer detected when plugging it and plugging it out.
I tried it on a windows machine also, but obviously that computer couldn't handle it neither and said that the drivers for the usb stick didn't work.

So here i am, with a broken USB stick and can't even format it since linux doesn't give it a label. I do not care about the data on the drive, just want to fix it.

Does anyone have any ideas what i could do?

this is what dmesg returns when plugging in the USB-drive:

```
[989699.588042] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[989699.722098] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[989721.936053] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[989732.180053] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[989748.424054] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[989748.672037] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[989758.916054] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[989759.049323] scsi 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry if this does not help, but did you try booting the pc with the stick plugged in to see if it recognizes it? i guess so the bios can see it.

i found this thread working on something similar.

i did a dd for an iso, now my stick will not automount. i thought i bricked it, but left it in the slot and noticed it was blinking when i rebooted the machine. at that time i ran dd again to undo the original hybrid config "that distro!!" needed. once i had a single partition again, i formatted it and then i could write to it. but it was still not automounting.

so now, i can only access it, if i boot with it in the usb slot and if i remove it during a session, lsblk no longer sees it, but lsusb does, as well as a syslog that has led me nowhere.

output of syslog

```
usb 1-2: can't set config #1, error -110
mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2"   
mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
```

it i have to reboot the pc to get hold of it again. i've redone dd, tried testdisk, gparted (made new partition table) and did a 'clean all' in windows disk part. it will even boot the pc with systemrescue, but it will not automount.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the case.
You are right, it is detected in lsusb and in bios. I havn't rebooted my machine in multiple weeks, will do that when i can. I also get the same error message: `mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device`

Answer (score 0):

Did try Gparted? It will let you put a new partition table on it, then create a new one, then apply operations.

Comment: Like i said, the kernel isn't even giving it a label so gparted doesn't even show the device.